# C# RichTextBox: Highlighting + Undo

Tags: c#, richtextbox, undo

I'm doing a simple xhtml editor with syntax highlighting.
The problem is that in richtextbox undo history everything is stored. Even my highlighting changes.
I already found that there is a `richtextbox.UndoActionName` which should be "Unknown" if you change the richtextbox programatically. So I tried something like this when ctrl+z is pressed:

```
while(richtextbox.CanUndo && richtextbox.UndoActionName == "Unknown"){
    richtextbox.Undo();
}
```

Which just selected my whole text and did not actually undo anything (just kept looping until I stopped it...).
So my question is whether I need to specify somewhere the undoactionname myself or whether I can change the richtextbox to record undo history only for typing?
Thanks.

**Edit:** It would be cool if I could send a message to richtextbox to stop recording undo history while i'm highlighting or to somehow exclude or actions with Unknown name, is there any way to do this?

**Edit 2:** Well I've done it the stupid way, I'm storing the whole text in linked list and when redoing I clear the richtextbox and fill it with last item from the list and then re-highlight. Maybe this helps anyone

Comment: Well I've done it the stupid way, I'm storing the whole text in linked list and when redoing I clear the richtextbox and fill it with last item from the list and then re-highlight. Maybe this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to undo last action, which will be an undo for next operation, hence it will keep doing that.

Try this:

```
while(richtextbox.CanUndo) {
  richtextbox.Undo();
  // Clear the undo buffer to prevent last action from being
  richtextbox.ClearUndo();
}
```

Comment: I'll try this later but I don't think this will work. This will undo last action (which is most probably syntax highlighting) and then clear the undo buffer. I want to skip all the syntax highlighting changes and undo to typing changes. Or does the ClearUndo() delete only the last undo item in history?